# Auto-sizing table cells with something other than label iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I implement a table cell that auto-resizes itself based on whether I hide or show a view in the cell? Or alternatively add a view, but adding means I can't see it in storyboard.

All the examples I have seen on auto-resizing table cells involve using just a label and having it expand when the label has more lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Auto Layout to create self-sizing table view cells check this link for detailed solution
https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

```
    myTable.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0
    myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    myTableView.autoresizesSubviews=true
```

by applying code above your tableView cell's will expand to fit content size